# Can I stop axis ticks from being drawn over axis lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm customizing a `ggplot` graph's appearance with a theme involving thick, dark axis lines. However, I've noticed that a plot with both ticks and axis lines will draw the ticks after it draws the lines.

That's not a problem with a thin axis, since the tick starts at the edge of the default axis line thickness. But if you make the line thicker, you end up with the tick being drawn OVER the line:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_light() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
          axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 2))
```

[image: Ticks being drawn over the chart axis]

Is there a way to get the ticks to be drawn under the axis line? To start them at the axis line's extent instead of its midpoint? Or otherwise to include both ticks and a thick axis line of a different color from the ticks without this odd overlap? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to change the order so that ticks are drawn under the axis lines within ggplot, but it can be done if you convert the plot to a grob.

For demonstration, here's a plot with ugly but obvious colour contrasts:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "yellow", size = 1),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "pt"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
```

[image: original plot]

In the above plot, the yellow tick lines are clearly above the black axis lines.

```
# convert to grob object
pg <- ggplotGrob(p) 

# swap order for y-axis
orig.order <- pg$grobs[[which(pg$layout$name == "axis-l")]]$childrenOrder
pg$grobs[[which(pg$layout$name == "axis-l")]]$childrenOrder <- orig.order[2:1]

# swap order for x-axis
orig.order <- pg$grobs[[which(pg$layout$name == "axis-b")]]$childrenOrder
pg$grobs[[which(pg$layout$name == "axis-b")]]$childrenOrder <- orig.order[2:1]

rm(orig.order)

# plot
grid::grid.draw(pg)
```

[image: new plot]

In the above plot, the yellow tick lines are now below the black axis lines.

Comment: This wasn't the solution I was hoping for, but it turned out to be the solution I needed! I still with this was possible in base ggplot, but I had other needs for the theme I'm writing that turned out to be only possible by going into `gtable` and your answer helped give me a starting point to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the ticks in similar way to the way you modified the axis line using `axis.ticks` and `axis.ticks.length`. For example:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(2, "mm"))
```

Comment: So this would solve the problem by making the ticks the same color as the line, correct?

Comment: Yes, and making them longer so they extend beyond the line